# Upload files to database (Servlet + JSP + MySQL)

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am following the example described in "http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql" url.

I am getting error in UploadServlet.java file line no 36. Rest of the things I configured and no issues.

```
 Please can anybody help me in this regards.
```

Thanks in advance,
        Neha.

Comment: Copy paste the error logs.More info you provide, will only help us to help you faster

Answer (score 1):

you must annotate your servlet with @MultipartConfig.

Sample:

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)<br/>
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```